# how to show name of each category

Tags: django

I have the following django code:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I edit a section, I see

`Category`: with drop down menu that says Category Object, Category Object

How do I show the name of each category object so the drop down menu will be something like `Cat`, `Dog` (like the actual names of the categories

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Try using `str` instead of `unicode`, I am using `python 2.7` and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```